# PHP header location not redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, header

I was trying to make a hangman game with php add I got the whole thing to work, execpt that if you run out of guesses it doesn't redirect to fail.php. The weird thing is that is does redirect if you win. I don't know whats wrong this is my quess_letter.php file:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$letter = $_POST['letter'];
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]$/', $letter)) {

    $guesses = intval(substr($_COOKIE['hangman'], 0, 1));

    $word = explode(" ", $_COOKIE['hangman_word']);
    if (!strpos($_COOKIE['hangman_word'], $letter) && $letter != substr($_COOKIE['hangman_word'], 0, 1)) {
        $guesses -= 1;
        if ($guesses == 0) {
            header("location: fail.php");
        }
    }

    $i = 0;
    foreach(str_split($word[0]) as $l) {
        if ($l == $letter) {
            $word[1][$i] = $l;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $new_cookie = strval($guesses) . " " . substr($_COOKIE['hangman'], 1) . $letter . " ";

    setcookie('hangman', $new_cookie, time() + 3600 * 24);
    setcookie('hangman_word', "$word[0] $word[1]", time() + 3600 * 24);
    if ($word[0] != $word[1]) {
        header("location: index.php");
    } else {
        header("location: win.php");
    }
} else {
    header("location: index.php?error=true");
}

?>
```

This is the whole file. It's supposed to redirect when $guesses is equal to 0. And theres nothing being printed before the redirect. I've researched it and none of the answers worked. Could someone explain what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: ok this doesn't solve your issue, but i think you should go with javascript.

Comment: Ya thats a good idea, I just started learning PHP so I wanted to do a project in it so I could get used to it, otherwise I would have.

Comment: you do know that cookies can be modified right?

Comment: No, I just started learning php like 3 days ago, and I learned cookies today

Comment: Echo all the data out at the end so you can test, from both cookies and then you can see if it actually achieves the required conditions on the if statement.

Comment: Well I put an echo thing in the if statement and it ran, it just doesn't redirect.

Comment: Where is $guesses getting set originally? It may make more sense to add up guesses (and check it's above the max) than count down...if you're not setting $guesses in the cookie somewhere else then it will always be < 0 since I believe intval will default to 0 and then you're decreasing it...

Comment: Ill try that, but in my index.php it shows the updated $guesses but once it gets to 1, it keeps decreasing until it gets to -1, I dont know why though. Theres a demo [here](http://addisonbean.com/hangman)

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your are sure that $guesses  will get to '**0**' exactly then

try

```
if ($guesses == 0) 
{
header("location: fail.php");
exit(); 
}
```